# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID Angular 4

Tags: spring-boot, ssl

I am implementing the SSL for my backend and the UI from a secure data communication. My backend is in Springboot and UI is in angular. I have already generated the jks for my backend and my backend apis are now https.

But , as soon as i changes the application(UI) url to https i cannot make backend calls using UI.

It's giving me `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`

Do i need to do any changes for the UI ?

Comment: Have you cors permission activated?

Comment: @Sam Yes my CORS fiters are in place and i can able to make http calls.

Comment: @Rohitesh I know that's a quite old question, but I want to know how did you solve this problem, I'm having the same. Thanks.

Comment: @RicardoAlves hello Ricardo with the self signed certificate chrome is not allowing to access anymore, so i now i am going with valid certificate to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try to execute:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --disable-gpu
```

Comment: It is not good way the disable the security of chrome at all.